# Select-object For Deeper JSON Data

Tags: json, powershell

I am having some issue selecting an object with powershell. I am trying to select the password value from this output utilizing powershell.

I tried this and i was unable to dive in deeper than this. How does one go deeper with the multiple fields?

```
Select-object -property id,@{Name= 'password'; Expression = {$_.items.itemValue}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Get-Content` as well as `ConvertFrom-JSON` to create Powershell Custom Objects, and then manipulate that instead of worrying about complicated text find-and-replace.

```
$myobject = (Get-Content yourfile.json) -join '`n' | ConvertFrom-Json
$password = $myobject.items[2].itemValue
```

Once you have the item you want stored in the variable you want, it should be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: Use `-Raw` instead of `-join` (although they're both equally unnecessary and your join will append the \`n instead of inserting a newline)

Comment: Ah - I've been mimicking the example in the help documentation for ConvertFrom-Json out of habit.  If it's unnecessary feel free to edit my answer to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

To go further, I think you should filter for the cases where you actually have a password to work with:

```
$obj = Get-Content -Path /conf.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$obj.Items | Where-Object { $_.fieldName -eq 'Password' } |
    Select-Object -Property @(
        @{
            N = 'Id'
            E = { $obj.Id }
        }
        @{
            N = 'Password'
            E = { $_.itemValue }
        }
    )
```